# Adding compilation behavior to ScriptSharp(Script#)

Tags: script#

I need to change the [script#](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp) compiler's code to add an `Attribute` to use on classes to generate javascript types just like [extjs new class system](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/class_system)

after some crawlings on the source from [github](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp) i found the compiler's dll on `nikhilk-scriptsharp-f7215c5\bin\ref\ScriptSharp.dll`

but the compiler source codes is not available on [github](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp)

Is script# OpenSource? and if yes where i can download the compiler source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've covered this pretty much over github and direct mail, until such a point where the sources for the compiler will join the other sources for the broader script# project in the github repo.

That said, one way to rethink the problem is to simply rewrite mscorlib.js.

mscorlib.js provides the type system contract that the compiler expects... for example, that there is an API called Type.registerClass and so on and so forth. Type.registerClass and related methods could be completely reimplemented to serve as a bridge to a different OOP simulation such as the Ext class system.

And yes, the sources for mscorlib.js are already in the github repository.

Comment: i already implemented new sencha class system, using decompiling your ScriptSharp.dll, but why the ScriptSharp.dll source code is not available on the github?